# How do I block calls to a specific endpoint in EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an open port for a server I am hosting, and I get lots of spurious calls to "/ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application" which seems to be for some Hadoop botnet (all it does is pollute my logs with lots of invalid URL errors). How do I block calls to this URL? I could change my port to a less common one but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to "block" such requests from reaching your server would be to launch an AWS Web Application Firewall (AWS WAF) and configure appropriate rules.

AWS WAF only works in conjunction with Amazon CloudFront or an Elastic Load Balancer, so the extra effort (and expense) might not be worth the benefit of simply avoiding some lines in a log file.

One day I took a look at my home router's logs and I was utterly amazed to see the huge amount of bot attempts to gain access to random systems. You should be thankful if this is the only one getting through to your server!